# Move IIS 7.5 FTP services from one server to another without recreating accounts

Tags: iis-7.5

I have an IIS 7.5 FTP server running in User Isolation mode on Windows Server 2008R2. I need to move the FTP services to a different server but I do not want to recreate every FTP account. Is the user configuration stored in a file I can just move from one server to the other one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are these local accounts or domain accounts?  If these are local accounts, they can't be moved.  Are these IIS or windows users?  You can review the applicationHost.config (make a backup copy first) and see what configuration is stored in there.   I asked a question about moving IIS manager users to another machine, a MS team member mentioned this.  We need a bit more information.  As far as moving the configuration over.  You could try copying the sites configuration specific to the FTP site by copying and pasting the particular configuration. This involves the XML so it's not very straight forward, but is an option.

http://forums.iis.net/t/1107088.aspx/1

Comment: They are local accounts and I was able to copy from the administration.config to get the accounts from one server to the other (%windir%\system32\inetsrv\config\administration.config). I had to redo the mappings but I got the accounts and passwords so it was all good.